# Вернуть строки из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js

Друзья, здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемкой, нужно взять из исходного массива несколько значений и поместить их впереди, при этом вернуть массив отдельными строкам. Как это реализовать, у меня получилось, что заданные `positions3.unshift(deLorean, wayY);` возвращаются как массивы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
var positions3 = 
[
    'Отвертка ультразвуковая WHO-D',
    'Ховерборд Mattel 2016',
    'Нейтрализатор FLASH black edition',
    'Меч световой FORCE (синий луч)',
    'Машина времени DeLorean', //4
    'Репликатор домашний STAR-94',
    'Лингвенсор 000-17',
    'Целеуказатель электронный WAY-Y'
],
number3 = 0,
deLorean = positions3.slice(4, 6),
wayY = positions3.slice(7, 8);

positions3.splice(4, 2);
positions3.splice(5, 1);
positions3.unshift(deLorean, wayY);
console.log(positions3);

var positions3Length = positions3.length;

while(number3 < positions3Length)
{
    console.log(positions3[number3++]);
}
```

Comment: [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator): `positions3.unshift(...deLorean, ...wayY);`

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, решил вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте следующее решение, должно прояснить ситуацию

```
var positions3 = 
[
  'Отвертка ультразвуковая WHO-D',
  'Ховерборд Mattel 2016',
  'Нейтрализатор FLASH black edition',
  'Меч световой FORCE (синий луч)',
  'Машина времени DeLorean', //4
  'Репликатор домашний STAR-94',
  'Лингвенсор 000-17',
  'Целеуказатель электронный WAY-Y'
];

var arrMagic = (function(arr) {
  function setPosToBegin(pos) {
    arr.unshift(arr.splice(pos, 1));
  };

  function toStringArr() {
    return arr.join('\n');
  };

  var API = {
    setPosToBegin: setPosToBegin,
    toStringArr: toStringArr
  };

  return API;
})(positions3);

arrMagic.setPosToBegin(4);
console.log(arrMagic.toStringArr());
```

Comment: Уже решился вопрос, выше человек комментарий оставил, 1 строкой все. Вообще этот код оказался нагруженным все можно в пару строк сделать.

Comment: Твой код работает не так как нужно. Так как [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) возвращает **массив** удаленных, когда ты делаешь unshift в исходный массив вставляется массив, а не отдельный элемент. Точно также как сейчас происходит у автора вопроса